# Performance counter for Node.JS

Tags: node.js, performance-testing

I am asking for your help.
I spent a day searching a tool like performance counter in **.NET** platform that let me measure some metrics in **node.js** (like number of requests, time execution and so on...)
Can you please give some hints?

Thanks

Comment: `console.time("key")` to start a benchmark, and `console.timeEnd("key")` to stop it. (it will print the time ellapsed)

Comment: Yes, I used that, but I have other metrics. I also used nodejsdashboard. Thanks anyway.